# File I/O Throughput

Tags: ubuntu, performance, ibm, io

I have an IBM x3650 M4 server (64-bit) running Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop (32-bit). I realize that this is a non-standard setup by it's being driven by other requirements. I am seeing slow file writes accross the board (to HDD, to USB, to network mount). The file writes seem to peek at 1.3Mb/s. The expected speed of my RAID setup is 180Mb/s.

Here's what I tried:

1. Boot Live Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit. The file writes are as expected, 180Mb/s.
2. Boot Live Ubuntu 13.04 32-bit. The file writes are slow, 1.3Mb/s.
3. Boot Live Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit.  The file writes are slow, 1.3Mb/s.
4. Boot Live Fedora 19 32-bit. The files writes are again as expected, 180Mb/s.

At this point, it looks like something in the Ubuntu 13.04 32-bit kernel is not being configured correctly to work with the IBM hardware. Fedora 32-bit seems to work just fine.

Would anyone happen to know what could be causing this?

Comment: Please list the filesystem (e.g. ext3 or ext4) for each along with the options (e.g. noatime) to make sure you are comparing apples to apples.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not note any of that info.  Live CDs were used with default options.

Comment: I suspect that write barriers are being sent where the performance is poor.